Regra gramatical de "enriquecer"
Qual a regra gramatical envolvida na pronúncia do R forte (som de rr) na palavra enriquecer?
Percebi que esse uso não ocorre na maioria dos encontros vocálicos, mas não consegui pensar em exemplos de palavras com a ocorrência de jr, lr ou zr no meio.
A dúvida veio ao ler a marca Sanremo de uma jarra plástica e lembrei apenas de enriquecer como outro exemplo.

O que é: jr, lr ou zr no meio??

Não é uma regra gramatical, mas apenas de pronúncia. A Wikipédia explica isso assim:

Os dois fonemas róticos, /ʁ/ e /ɾ/, sofrem contraste apenas quando entre vogais. No início das palavras e depois de /l/, /z/, /ʒ/ e de vogais nasais apenas a primeira ocorre e nos conjuntos consonantais (ex: pr, fr, cr,...) apenas o segundo acontece, enquanto em outras situações a maioria dos dialetos usa apenas a segunda. No entanto, diversos dialetos brasileiros, entre eles o dialeto carioca, utilizam-se da segunda no final das sílabas.


Interessante, ontem fiquei pensando em exemplos e contra exemplos e percebi que pra todos os encontros de nr a segunda pronúncia é sempre usada (enraizar, enredo, enrosco e enrugado) e os únicos contra exemplos que consegui pensar foram nomes próprios como do Ezra Miller e do saudoso Antônio Abujamra

A pronúncia faz parte da gramática.

Contexto
Primeiro vamos entender algumas coisas.
A gramática são as regras ou a descrição de uma língua ignorando mudanças que não mudam o significado. Assim, ela se importa com a diferença entre "eu gosto dele" e "dele eu gosto", porque há mudança na estrutura da frase: "dele" está em outro lugar; é verdade que a segunda enfatiza "dele", mas isto não importa para a gramática. Em compensação, a gramática não vê diferença entre "Eu gosto DELE!" e "Eu gosto dele...".
O estudo da pronúncia são a fonética e fonologia. A fonologia, parte da gramática, estuda os sons que mudam o sentido da palavra, chamados "fonemas". A fonética estuda qualquer "som articulado da fala", chamados "fones". Para a fonética, as últimas vogais de "eli" (pronúncia comum) e "ele" (pronúncia do Sul brasileiro) são diferentes; mas como esta duas pronúncias de "e" expressam a mesma vogal sem mudar o sentido da palavra, estes dois fones (sons) representam o mesmo fonema. É meio confuso mesmo.
Resposta
Em português, há realmente só uma pronúncia hoje em dia do "r" em "enriquecer", que é o som do "h" em "HaHa!". Porém, este "h" pode ter várias pronúncias dependendo do indivíduo e contexto, mas acabam sendo tão semelhantes que chamamos de varição em português. A reposta de "tchrist" lista algumas pronúncias com a escrita do AFI.

Bem notado, seria essa a mesma explicação para a pronúncia de "companhia" ignorar o encontro de nh?

@AsAves, algumas falam esse nh como em "aranha", como a minha mãe. Depende da pessoa.
